# simulating the estimatiors in matlab

Tags: matlab, simulink, measurement

I have an assignment like this but I do not know where to start( sorry I do not know much about Matlab). I have struggled with the variable C( how can I pass the value into it when its range is unknown?) and these blocks at the bottom as well. I have to do something like Simulink or just coding to achieve it. I have searched on the internet but I do not see anything related to my task. Or maybe I use the wrong keywords to find it. Could you give me some suggestion or links which are relevant to this. Thank you so much!
[image: required task]

Comment: Poorly worded problems confusing students' heads... your instructor might be the one who needs help, methinks. Anyway, if you don't mind writing a regular program, just follow the direction of the arrows and write each operation one step at a time. You can begin by creating a function that takes as inputs the four `sigma`s and `mu`s, the two `rho`s, `f_0`, `N`, `t_0` and `delta t`. To generate values for your random variables, take a look at [mvnrnd](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/mvnrnd.html). (The Communications Toolbox might have useful routines as well, but I'm not familiar with it.)

Comment: We are studying measurement theory, our teacher just teaches us theoretical formulas, lots of integration, derivatives,..etc. So when it comes to Matlab( also our major has nothing to do with matlab, we study embedded system, so we are more familiar with chips, sensors,.etc), we do not know what to do. The seniors told me that they also just copied everything from an old solution, no one can solve it in recent semesters. However, I want to try my best.

Comment: Ah yes the standard university approach to teaching MATLAB. I had to spend a day being taught how to use MS Office but when it came to MATLAB, we too, were thrown in at the deep end.